# Filtering Facebook Graph API Wall Feed (Profile Feed)

Tags: json, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to retrieve items from my wall with a url in the following form: https://graph.facebook.com/mypage/feed?callback=?&limit=50&access_token=xxxxx

However, only one third of the items returned in the feed are actually "from me". The rest of them are messages "to me" from various Facebook users and I do not want to display them. I'm currently using JS to filter the items if the "from" json item contains my numeric id. Is there a way to filter this directly at the feed level rather than in my JavaScript app? I was thinking of something like &from=4342xxx but of course it doesn't work as expected.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with an FQL query like:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```